# Location of the current theme json file for WordPress Site Editor so I can add custom font?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to add a custom font to my WordPress site using the Site Editor ( wp-admin/site-editor.php ).

I'm using a twentytwentyfour child theme and have created a new json file at:

```
/wp-content/themes/twentytwentyfour-child/styles/mystyle.json
```

before selecting it in the **Browse styles >** area of Site Editor.

I have then added a new woff2 font to the `settings.typography.fontFamilies` section of `mystyle.json` as described [here](https://fullsiteediting.com/lessons/theme-json-typography-options/).

However, the changes I make to that file seem to be ignored by the WP Site Editor.

It seems WP is no longer checking my `mystyle.json` style so I would like to know where/how to add my new fonts?